# Can't remove untracked changes at Git (x1 deleted and x1 modified file)

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm having a big trouble with my local repository. I'm currently using Git Flow so when a new development has to be started, I went to "develop" branch but I always found that there are 2 changes at my working directory:

```
 D "src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other: (UseCase) Refactor naming"
?? src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other
```

I tried those things to remove that changes and start working at a clean environment:

- Removed all local repository and clone it again making sure no Git GUI client or IDE is opened.
- Executed `git clean`, `reset`, `checkout`... sometimes the *"??"* marked is
  removing, the *"D"* one isn't going anywhere

I'm relatively new at Git and I want to know what can I do to have a clean working directory.

Thanks (and sorry for my english hehe)!

Answer (score 2):

First, this appears to be output from `git status --short`:

> ```
>  D "src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other: (UseCase) Refactor naming"
> ?? src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other
> ```

If that's *not* the case, some of my suppositions below may be incorrect.

Now, before we go any further, let's make a couple of notes about Git (you mention that you're "relatively new" and I don't know if any tutorials you've read have been any good).  Git is really all about *commits:* a Git repository is a collection of commits, plus other internal Git objects that Git needs to make commits actually work, stored in a big database that Git calls the *object database* (or just "objects").

Commits have *hash IDs*, which are really just very large, random-looking (but not actually *random*), numbers, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), such as `e4a4b31577c7419497ac30cebe30d755b97752c5`.  Each commit gets a *unique* hash ID, and Git *needs* these hash IDs to find the commits.  But humans are very bad at hash IDs (change one hex-digit in the middle of that big ugly string and challenge someone to tell you if it's changed or not; even with both up on the screen, they might have a lot of trouble finding the changed digit!).  So a Git repository also gives us *branch and tag names* for instance, and we generally use those to find the commits: Git maintains the mapping for us, so we can just say `main` or `develop` or whatever.

The important thing for you here is this:

> ... when a new development has to be started, I went to "develop" branch

**The name `develop` means *some particular commit*.  Because it's a *branch* name, the commit—the hash ID—that it means may change over time.  But *right now* it means a commit that, I believe, has an error in it!**

Assuming I'm correct, you simply need to fix the error and move on.  When someone (perhaps also you, perhaps someone else) fixes *just* the error and adds that fixed-up commit *to* the `develop` branch, you won't have to keep fixing the error any more, but for now you'll have to fix the error yourself.

#### Fixing the error

To fix the error in the commit, you must commit the removal of a file.  The problem you're going to have is that your computer—probably a Windows machine—can't have that file in the first place.  That particular problem is part of its own solution, but it's *causing* the second problem.

To fix the *second* problem, you just need to remove the untracked file.  Using whatever your computer's command is for removing a file, remove the file named `src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other`.  (You can use `git clean` for this, as in [Akzy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72799938/1256452), or some more basic `rm` or `del` command.)  The two-question-marks in the `git status --short` output will disappear, leaving you with the other space-and-D-status file.

To fix *that* problem, you just need to tell Git that *that* file should be gone as well.  To do that, run:

```
git add "src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other: (UseCase) Refactor naming"
```

or more simply:

```
git add -u
```

The output from `git status --short` will now read:

```
D  "src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other: (UseCase) Refactor naming"
```

That is, the letter `D` will move one column to the left.  The output from `git status` *without* `--short` will tell you that this deletion is "staged for commit".  Then run `git commit` and supply a useful commit message.  Different teams have different standards for what goes into a commit message, but something like:

```
remove trash file

Remove a file left over by some editor or generation software
that was accidentally committed earlier.  This file can't be
extracted on Windows systems, and has no useful data.
```

might be OK.

This commit is now suitable to be added *to* the `develop` branch.

## Optional reading: What's going on, in gory detail

A Git *commit* is a two-part entity.  Each commit stores two things:

- The commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*.  This snapshot acts like an archive: a tar, WinRAR, zip, etc., archive, for instance.  It lets you "go back in time" to the time at which whoever *made* the commit, made the commit.  By storing a full snapshot, rather than a set of changes, Git makes it very easy to go directly to that snapshot.

  The files inside this snapshot, however, are stored in a very special (and rather magical and Gitty) format, so that your repository doesn't grow hugely fat as you make new commits.  Git's author observed a simple fact: in a big project with hundreds, or thousands, or even millions of files, most *commits* only *change* one or maybe a few files.  So if we can *re-use* the files from previous commits, we can save a lot of space.  Moreover, depending on exactly *how* we do the re-use, we easily tell that commit C (from early on in the project) and commit H (from later) still have exactly the same files in some directory, and only changed one file in some other folder, for instance.

  Committed files, and other Git internal objects, are later even-further-compressed, but the initial de-duplication *always* takes place *immediately*.  So no particular version of any file is ever stored more than once in the first place, and Git can easily tell if you're still using (or have gone back to) the old version.
- Meanwhile, each commit also stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes things like who made the commit and when, and the log message we mentioned for `git commit` above.  There's more in the metadata but we won't worry about it here, to keep this short-ish.

All parts of every commit are frozen for all time once you (or whoever) make the commit.  No part of any commit can ever be changed!  That's what enables the file-sharing, for instance.  That's obviously good for keeping the repository from getting too fat, but it presents a problem: if the files *in* a commit are all read-only—and they are—how are we ever going to get any *new work* done?

Git's answer here is the same as in most traditional version control systems (VCSes).  They *all* have this problem: a snapshot, once made, *shouldn't* be changed, and depending on how the VCS works, sometimes it really *can't* be (as is true in Git).  So VCSes generally separate what you're doing into two parts: there's the *repository*, where the commits are stored, and a separate *working tree*.  **The working tree is where you do your work.**

It's just a place—a folder or directory in your file system—where, instead of archived committed frozen files (which in Git's case are in some Gitty format that you probably can't even read), you have ordinary everyday files.  **It's important for you to realize that these files *are not in Git*.**  Git *extracted* them from a commit, and Git can use them to make a *new* commit, but while you're working on / with them, they're just ordinary files, stored in ordinary folders.

If Git were like all the other VCSes, it would stop here, with the two copies of each file: the one for the *current commit* (which is where Git got the file it put in your working tree), and the working tree one (the one that's an ordinary file but is not *in* Git at all).  But here's where Git gets weird and different: Git keeps a *third copy*, or maybe I should say "copy", of each file.

This third "copy" of each file sits kind of *between* the commit and your working tree.  It's stored in the Gitty *format*, but it's not actually frozen like the committed copy.  It is, however, *pre-de-duplicated*.  That's why it makes sense to put "copy" in quotes.  When we first start out to do some work, we *check out* some commit, with `git checkout develop` or `git switch develop`, and Git:

- fills in our working tree with normal copies of each file, but also
- fills in its *index* or *staging area* with "copies" of the Git-ized de-duplicated file.

This index [aka](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aka) staging area holds that "third copy", and since every file *in* it just came *out of a commit*, every file in the index is a duplicate.  So it's de-duplicated and takes essentially no space.<sup>1</sup>  The *main things to know about this index copy* are:

1. It exists.  Its existence is what makes a file *tracked*.
2. It's pre-de-duplicated, i.e., ready to be committed *right now*.
3. It's what will go into the *next commit you make*.
4. Running `git add` updates or, in one case, removes it.

When you run `git commit`, Git packages up all the files that are in the index *right then*, as of the form they have *right then*, and those are the files that go into the *next* commit.

What this means is that when you're working in your working tree, you're not actually doing anything Git-specific yet!  You just do your work, maybe build a program or test your Python code or whatever, and generally make some progress.  Once you're *ready to commit* the code or other files, though, you *must* run `git add`.  That's true even if the file came out of Git before.

What you are doing when you run `git add` on an updated file is telling Git:

- Read the working tree copy of the file.
- Compress it into the de-duplicated, Gitty format.  Check for duplicates!
- If it's a duplicate, use the original!  Otherwise make it ready for commit.
- In either case, update the *index* aka *staging area*.

So it's at `git add` time that the file is prepped for the next commit.  Running `git commit` just commits whatever is in the *index* aka *staging area*.

Some people like to use `git commit -a`.  I generally discourage this, because people who do this seem to be doing it so that they can *ignore* the staging area.  This mostly works until they hit one of the weird cases in Git, which actually happens *a lot*, and then they're lost because they're not paying attention to Git's index.  You can use it if you like it, but remember that this is a short-cut and you're effectively running `git add -u`, which we'll cover more of in a moment.

---

<sup>1</sup>Each index entry does take a bit of space, roughly about 100 bytes per file depending on the length of the file's name, for the stuff you'll see if you run `git ls-files --stage`—this command doesn't *change* anything, but in a big repository, it produces a *lot* of output—plus a bunch of cache data that you'll only see if you use `--debug` with your `ls-files` command.  But with modern file and disk sizes, this is practically nothing.

---

#### Some of the trickier cases

Item 1 above—that each index entry *exists* in the first place, and that this is what makes a file *tracked*—is our first stumbling block.  Remember that your working tree, where you're doing your work, is an *ordinary folder* in your computer.  Git has no control over it!  You can do anything you want here, including create all-new-files, or remove existing files.

When you do either of these—create an all-new file, or remove an existing file—*nothing happens to Git's index yet*.  It still has in it all the entries it had before.

If you make an all-new file, you *must* use `git add` to copy a Git-ized version of the file *into* Git's index.  This `git add` reads and compresses the file as usual, checks for duplicates as usual—you might be duplicating the content of some existing file, or some file committed five years ago—and does all the usual stuff as above, but instead of *kicking some previous version of this-named-file out of the index* and putting in this version, it just puts this one in.  If you made a new file `path/to/file.ext`, you get a *new* index entry named `path/to/file.ext`.

You can use `git add -u`, but that tells Git: *scan through all the files that are in the index right now, and `git add` any that I updated in my working tree*.  If you added an *all-new file*, well, that's not in Git's index *right now*.  So `git add -u` won't *add* it.  So `git commit -a` won't *commit* it either: as I noted above, `git commit -a` is like running `git add -u` first.  Once you've used `git add` to *add* it to the index, *then* it's in the index (right now) and *now* you can use `git add -u` or `git commit -a`.  But you have to `git add` it at least this once.

What if you *remove* a file from your working tree?  Well, the file is still there in Git's index of course.  But if you now run:

```
git add path/to/file/I/removed
```

Git will notice that the file is *gone*, and this time, Git will actually *remove the index copy*.  (Remember that this doesn't affect any commit: it's at most removing a de-duplicated duplicate, not the original.)  Now that the index copy is *gone*, if you create the file again, it's *untracked* and you need to `git add` it again.

Using `git add -u` on a file you've removed actually *works*, because `git add -u` means *scan through all the index entries*, and that scans through the file you didn't remove from Git's index yet.  Git checks to see if you've updated the working tree copy, and notices that you *removed* the working tree copy, and `git add` then removes the index copy.  It's a funny (weird) command, `git add`: it sometimes removes things!

There is also a `git rm` command.  Using `git rm`, e.g.:

```
git rm path/to/file.ext
```

tells Git to remove the file from *both* your working tree *and* Git's own index.  So this is a convenient way to discard both versions: the to-be-committed, Git-ified and de-duplicated index copy *and* the working tree copy.  Note that:

```
git rm --cached
```

tells Git to remove only the *index* copy, leaving the working tree copy alone.  This is a little weird, but has some uses.

#### Git vs Windows and some other operating systems and file systems

When Git stores a file in a commit, or in its index, Git:

- always uses forward slashes: files have names like `path/to/file.ext`, not `path\to\file.ext`;
- allows almost every character to be in a file name, including `:`;
- allows almost every possible *name*, including e.g., `aux.h` or `aux.py`.

Windows, by contrast, uses backwards slashes (but allows you to use forward ones) and *forbids* `:` in names and *forbids* the name `aux`: you literally *can't* create a file named `aux.py` or `path/to/aux.py` (or `path\to\aux.py`).

This in particular is what's going wrong for you.  You have a *commit* that contains a file named `src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other: (UseCase) Refactor naming`, complete with the colon and parentheses.  Your system—whatever it is—doesn't like this name!  It's *dropping everything including and after the colon* and that produces the name `src/use_cases/aggregator/update_stores_status_use_case.py~other`, which your system *does* allow.

So, when Git tries to create the name with the colon in it, your system creates, instead, the *untracked file*.  Your Git doesn't notice this right away, but `git status` sees the file name that Git *didn't* try to create and sees that this name *isn't* in Git's index.  That makes this file an *untracked file*.  Meanwhile, the *tracked* file, in Git's index, is missing from the working tree: Git assumes *you* deleted it, and that's why it shows up as "deleted".

The file's name, shorn of folder-y bits, is `update_stores_status_use_case.py~other: (UseCase) Refactor naming`.  This is the kind of name that people create by accident, not the kind of name people put in on purpose.  The tilde character in particular *tends* to get used to mark files that shouldn't be `git add`-ed.

If this is the case for you—and that's something you'll need to verify somehow—then the solution is clear: remove the "junk" file and commit.  Your system has "helpfully" "pre-removed" the junk file by not being able to create it, but has "unhelpfully" created a *different* junk file.  You can simply remove it, perhaps after inspecting it to determine that it is indeed junk.  Or, if it actually has good stuff in it, you might be able to *rename* the file to something useful, `git add` it, and commit *that*.

In any case, the main thing to learn here is about the index (or "staging area") and its role in making *new commits*, vs how you actually get your work done with the working tree.  Note that when you run `git status`, Git actually runs *two separate comparisons:*

- First, Git compares the *current commit* to the index.  For every file that is *the same*, Git says *nothing at all*.  For files that are different, Git call them *staged for commit*.
- Second, Git compares the index vs your working tree.  For every file that is the same, Git says nothing; for files that are different, Git calls them *not staged for commit*.

Files that are in your working tree, but not in your index, are *untracked files* (rather than "added to the working tree").  This puts them into a special category and you can make `git status` shut up about them, but we'll leave that for later.

Using `--short` with `git status` tells Git to *combine* the two comparisons and print the staged and unstaged status values in the first two columns.  (If you're in the middle of an incomplete merge, you get a different set of columns—but again we'll leave that for later.)

Answer (score 1):

*Follow these steps to properly `git clean` files:*

***But***

### !! be very careful with these !!

### you may end up deleting what you don't want to

1. Run ‘git clean -n’ to see a dry run;
2. Run ‘git clean -f’ to force untracked file deletion;
3. Use ‘git clean -f -d’ to remove untracked directories;
4. Use ‘git clean -f -x’ to remove untracked .gitignore files; and
5. Add the -i switch to do an interactive ‘git clean

To see what will be deleted before-hand, without actually deleting it, use the `-n` flag (this is basically a test-run). When you are ready to actually delete, then remove the `-n` flag

```
git clean -nfd
```

Comment: Following your steps I ended up cleaning the one change with "??" but the "D" ones still on my working directory... :(

Comment: This is built-in command to cleanup the untracked files

Comment: You can read more here [ https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clean.html ]

Comment: And what can I do with the deleted file untracked change? I don't delete nothing and still appears as I do something 